# Changing git authentication from password to oauth token

Tags: git, github

Like the rest of you, I recently got an email from Github stating that I have recently accessed a repository with a password instead of a token. However, I cannot seem to figure out how I can tell the git on my AWS to forget that password, so I can re-authenticate pushes with the token.

Does anyone have a link to a guide on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your github password .. the authentication challenge will fail and you will be prompted for the new password .. at which point you can provide the personal access token instead.

Comment: Yup, this worked flawlessly. I had to add the -v flag to force verification rather than erroring and exiting, however.

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ explains how to do this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager):

> Usually, if the password or token is invalid, Git will erase it and prompt for a new one. However, there are times when this doesn’t always happen. To change the password or token, you can erase the existing credentials and then Git will prompt for new ones. To erase credentials, use a syntax like the following (substituting your username and the hostname):

```
$ echo url=https://author@git.example.org | git credential reject
```

In this case, you'll want to change the URL so it points to your username at `github.com`.